# How to work with discounts in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I want to implement a product discount feature within RavenDB.

Product doc:

```
{
  "RegularPrice": 10.00,
  "ReferencePrice": 0.0,
  "Categories": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ]
}
```

Now for example I'd like to give a discount for all products in category "A". 
So I map category on discount rate in a discounts document like this:

```
{
  "ProductDiscount": {
    "A": 20.0
  }
}
```

The question is how do I calculate the ReferencePrice and store or update it when:

- A new product is added?
- The RegularPrice is updated?
- The discounts document is updated?

It seems that I should handle this with a trigger. But I'm not sure!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this model will hold up.  How will you associate the product to the discount?  They are related by categories, but with this model, it's a many-to-many relationship.  Is this what you intended?  If so, how will you deal with having multiple discounts that could apply to the same product?

If you were to leave it like this, one strategy you could consider would be multi-map/reduce to calculate the price, and the [Indexed Properties Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/indexed-properties) to write the result back to the document.  But this is a pretty complicated setup.

You could probably make this easier by having a single discount per category, and defining the discount as part of the category document.  Then you could use [LoadDocument](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/static-indexes/indexing-related-documents) to pull in the discount for the categories while indexing.

You'll need to experiment with a model that fits your requirements *and* that you can maintain.

Other ideas:

- Yes, you could use a [trigger](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/plugins), but that would run server-side as a plugin.  It may be difficult to maintain.
- You could manually send a [scripted patch request](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/partial-document-updates) any time a category discount is applied.  New documents and edits to existing documents would have to be done manually in your own code.
- You could leave the calculated price off of the product completely.  Whenever loading a product, you'd include the discounts and calculate the price on the fly.

There are others, I'm sure.  It really depends on what works in your particular app.

Comment: thanx for your response.
Indeed, a product is related to multiple categories. In case of  multiple discounts, the lowest calculated price will be set.

Good suggestions and idea's, but some of them are not useful in my context.

- Using LoadDocument while indexing will not update the documents
- Trigger is an option, but maintaining will be an issue (in addition, I have no idea how to realize the solution with a trigger)
- Scripted patch request is an option too, but I prefer a mechanism that avoids manually work. 
- It is not desirable to calculate the price at run time

...

Comment: So there remains one option on; Indexed Properties Bundle. I have tried the following:
The index that will calculate the (discount) price:
`Map = products =>
                  from p in products
                  from c in p.Categories
                  select new
                  {
                      ProductId = p.Id,
                      ReferencePrice = p.RegularPrice * ((100 - LoadDocument<Discount>("Discount/" + c).Amount) / 100)
                  };`

...

Comment: And a document that mapps the index fields on product document properties

Comment: `documentstore.DatabaseCommands.Put("Raven/IndexedProperties/" + discountsIndex.IndexName,
                           null,
                           RavenJObject.FromObject(new IndexedPropertiesSetupDoc
                           {
                               DocumentKey = "ProductId",
                               FieldNameMappings =
                                       {
                                           { "ReferencePrice", "ReferencePrice" }
                                       }
                           }),
                           new RavenJObject());`